# How can I find google flights URL query parameters?

Tags: python, base64, decode, url-parameters, google-flights

I have been trying to scrape google flights:
I am using selenium python to automate google flights(https://www.google.com/travel/flights).

But selenium is slow and sometimes it's hard to automate a button or slide the price range. Luckily I found this answer on StackOverflow which shows how to use query strings on URL of google flights to filter output:
[How can I decode/recreate Google Flights Search URLs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68959917/how-can-i-decode-recreate-google-flights-search-urls)

`https://www.google.com/travel/flights?q=Flights%20to%20SFO%20from%20HNL%20on%202022-09-13%20through%202022-09-17`

But I want to use more filters like, stops, airlines,price, times... How can I do that in URL?